# HTML validation not working for input field loaded using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, validation

I have a form input field loaded by jquery based on user selection but the HTML form validation and even jquery form validation not working for the input field loaded by jquery.

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2">
      <select name="usdtnetwork" required="required" id="usdtnetwork" onChange="getaddressForm()" title="Please select your USDT Network">
         <option>::: Choose your USDT Network :::</option>
         <option value="ERC20">ERC20 (ETH)</option>
         <option value="TRC20">TRC20 (TRON)</option>
         <option value="BEP20">BEP20 (BNB)</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2">
      <div align="left"> 
         <span id="showinputfield"></span>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

This is my jquery (Noticed I tried `e.preventDefault()` but can't figure what am doing wrong so I commented it out)

```
<script>    
   /*$('.thisbuyUSDT').click(function (e) {
          
     var myForm = jQuery( "#catalog_formusdt" );
   
    // html 5 is doing the form validation for us,
    // so no need here (but backend will need to still for security)
    if ( ! myForm[0].checkValidity() )
    {
      // bonk! failed to validate, so return true which lets the
      // browser show native validation messages to the user
      return true;
    }
        e.preventDefault(); */                      
   function getaddressForm() {
   
   //e.preventDefault();
   $("#loaderIcon").show();
   jQuery.ajax({
   url: "usdt_form_field.php",
   data:'usdtnetwork='+$("#usdtnetwork").val(),
   type: "POST",
   success:function(data){
   $("#showinputfield").html(data);
   $("#loaderIcon").hide();
   },
   error:function (){}
   });
   }
   //}
</script>
```

Comment: Validation is working for other input fields, just the one loaded via jquery

Answer (score 0):

you have to reset validation on form after add some element (after $("#showinputfield").html(data);) by :

```
 myForm.removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(myForm );
```

if it doesn't work please share complete html and jquery code